# Agregar importación de función no funciona. .NET

Tags: c#, .net, mvc, entity-framework, stored-procedure

**Mi Problema**: Cuando selecciono "Actualizar" no se carga el cuadro de abajo:[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Qué estoy haciendo:** Quiero alimentar una vista usando un Stored Procedure, pero la vista me lanza un error:

> EntityFramework.dll pero no se controló en el código del usuario

Información adicional: The type 'p_AbandonCalls_Result' is mapped as a complex type. The Set method, DbSet objects, and DbEntityEntry objects can only be used with entity types, not complex types.

La parte donde se arroja el error es en el Controller:

```
public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View(db.abandonCalls.ToList());
    }
```

Justo encima de *abandonCalls*

Por último, sólo cargué el SP en el modelo, es decir, no hay ninguna table ni entidad que represente al SP.

Comment: Cómo estas llamando al SP? Podrías incluir ese código...

Comment: @PauloUrbanoRivera te refieres a cómo lo llamo desde la Vista?

Comment: No.. como lo llamas en back-end, imagino que el resultado lo guardas en una variable y desde ahí pasas ese resultado a la vista.